# How can I verify with the DB certain fields while using GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, graphql, graphql-js

I'm currently doing some research on how to implement GraphQL in my current project. There's something that concerns me... How do I verify with the database that the information that is being passed it's actually from that user? Both queries and mutations are grabbed from a single endpoint, which then the client is in charge of performing reads and writes to the DB respectively.

While I see how to validate by type (string, id, number, etc...) I don't see a hook or a moment in which I can verify that the possible Ids which are passed are in fact from the current user. E.g:

```
query {
  hero {
    name
  }
  droid(id: "2000") {
    name
  }
}
```

How can I check with the db, that the current id, 2000, belongs to the current user?

I'm currently using .NET Core MVC 2 (If that helps).

I would have done something like this using Entity Framework:
`_database.Droids.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

If that Id doesn't correspond to that user, it would return an empty object. Same goes for an insert operation (Mutation in GraphQL).

Is there a hook in which I can verify the data? How would I do it?

Thanks!

*I don't mind if there's an example in NodeJS or C#*

Comment: At that time I didn't know what I was talking about... "Resolvers", that's the name I've been looking for.